# Effect of recursion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion, stack-overflow

The following code segment demonstrates a recursive call using JavaScript.

```
function timedCount()
{
document.getElementById('txt').value=c;
c=c+1;
t=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000);
}
```

The source is from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

My question: Doesn't this lead to a stack build-up and subsequently a stack overflow? I know for a fact that this will certainly crash in languages like Pascal and C/C++.

Thanks for any advice on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not real recursion and thus does not create a deep call stack.

---

However, you should **never** pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in potentially unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable.

The proper solution is `setTimeout(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setInterval()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setTimeout(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

So in your case, use `t = setTimeout(timedCount, 1000);`

Comment: It's not right. Both things don't do the same thing. setInterval will enforce a time of msecs between each call, but pseudo-recursive setTimeout will prevent from having two executions to collide within the msecs, potentially leading to many simultaneous executions if the code to execute has to last longer than msecs.

Comment: @subtenante: Where did I tell him to use `setInterval()`?! That's a generic text for both cases and I even gave him an example using `setTimeout`. But I'll update it to make it clearear.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I appreciate the concept of using a call-back. I was more keen in the recursive routine.

From what I know, a function calling itself is recursion. How do you say it's not? Thanks again!

Comment: Well you said that the proper way to do it was to use setInterval. I must have understood that you recommended it. Glad  you edited.

Comment: @itsols: The function does not call itself. It schedules itself to be called asynchronously

Comment: @itsols The function isn't calling itself, it's passing itself to setTimeout to be called later by something else.

Comment: @David—correct. The function is calling `setTimeout`, which then calls `timedCount` as soon as it can after the interval has elapsed. It is a sequential call, not recursion.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't recursion, because your `timedCount()` function is not calling itself, it is calling `setTimeout()` to ask JS to call `timeCount()` *asynchronously* after the specified delay. The line after the one with `setTimeout()` - in this case just the end of the function - will execute immediately, it doesn't pause or sleep until after the timeout. So when you call `timedCount()` from somewhere else in your code `timedCount()` will finish executing and control will return to that other part of your code, then later the function will be called again via the timeout, which again causes another one to be scheduled for later execution (and so on ad infinitum). At no point is there a halfway finished `timedCount()` waiting for another one to finish executing like there would be with actual recursion.

If you did this:

```
function timedCount() {
   // other code here

   timedCount();
}
```

...then *that* would be recursion and would indeed crash since there are no conditions set to stop the recursion. If you add some control logic so that the recursion stops a "reasonable" number of levels deep that would be fine.

Comment: I figured that out with the very first answer I received. But your explanation is good as well. +1 for your efforts and time. Thanks!